# Why, even after changing boot priority on BIOS, USB device (Ubuntu) is ignored?

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, 22.04, windows-10

I am currently using Windows 10 in my laptop and I would like to install Ubuntu 22.04 (Or Ubuntu 20.04) in dual boot.

My laptop is a Acer Aspire F5-573g and the BIOS Mode is UEFI. I have already shrinked the original partition and created a new unallocated volume of 80 Gb. I used the software BalenaEtcher to burn Ubuntu 22.04 ISO file into a 32 Gb USB stick (Kingston DataTraveler Exodia, to be specific). I have accessed the BIOS and changed the boot priority with the USB device on top priority and Windows as the last option for booting, just to be sure. However, after few minutes, the computer boots with Windows 10.

How to fix this issue and boot with the USB device to install Ubuntu in dual boot mode?

Comment: Check your BIOS to see if removable device boot is enabled - sometimes it shows the boot options but won't boot proper to it.  Also, disable Fast Boot in Windows and do a full shut down.

Comment: Most Acer also require some special steps like "trust" after install. Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot